Why does it shows the following error of cookies.json of hugchat Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 58894)
While I was running the program of my chatbot in Python, when I give a prompt to the chatbot it shows this error:

Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 58894)


The chatbot uses the hugchat JSONimported from the cookies editor through the hugchat site.
I don't know why is it saying extra data like it was normal before.

Is your data potentially multiple rows/lines of json since the error is on line 2 and suggests the first json record was concidered complete? See if this helps Loading and parsing a JSON file with multiple JSON objects

If you have already used a JSON validator online or with python, you can make sure to clean (Remove comments or extra characters) the data to only keep what HugChat needs
